# Showing Date in TextBox [UWP]

Tags: uwp, calendar

I'm using a **CalendarView** and want to populate the date (single) selected by the user in a **textbox**.

I need the calendar to be always displayed, so I can't use Calendar DatePicker. And I'm unable to find any help from the documentations.
Any suggestions?

Comment: You can handle the `SelectedDatesChanged` event to update the text of the desired textbox

Comment: @Muzib I'm unable to do that. Could you kindly provide a piece of code as an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Muzib 's comment is correct, you could handle [`SelectedDatesChanged`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.calendarview.selecteddateschanged) event and get the select date from args.

```
MyCalendarView.SelectedDatesChanged += MyCalendarView_SelectedDatesChanged;

private void MyCalendarView_SelectedDatesChanged(CalendarView sender, CalendarViewSelectedDatesChangedEventArgs args)
{
    MyTextBox.Text = args.AddedDates.First().ToString();
}
```

Comment: Thanks, But is there a way to do so via Binding in XAML, instead of doing it in code behind?

Comment: CalendarView is  not same as DatePicker, it does not contains`SelectedDate` property, you could not could get date via Binding in XAML, but you could try to bind `SelectedDatesChanged` event then get the date in the view model

Comment: I'm trying **<CalendarView Name="MyCalendarView" SelectedDatesChanged="MyCalendarView_SelectedDatesChanged" SelectionMode="Single"/>** in XAML but it's not working. Could you provide an example please? Thanks.

Comment: Please refer this [document](https://github.com/Microsoft/XamlBehaviors/wiki/CallMethodAction).